# How can I move my media files stored in local machine to S3?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have a Django application running on EC2. Currently, all my media files are stored in the instance. All the documents I uploaded to the models are in the instance too. Now I want to add S3 as my default storage. What I am worried about is that, how am I gonna move my current media files and to the S3 after the integration.

I am thinking of running a Python script one time. But I am looking for any builtin solution or maybe just looking for opinions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon CLI should do the job:

```
aws s3 cp path/to/file s3://your-bucket/
```

or if the whole directory then:

```
aws s3 cp path/to/dir/* s3://your-bucket/ --recursive
```

All options can be seen here : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method would be to use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) `aws s3 sync` command. It can copy files to/from Amazon S3.

However, if there are complicated rules associated with where to move the files, then you certain use a Python script and the [`upload_file()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_file) command.

Comment: Thanks, I will try and let you know.

Comment: Tried "aws s3 copy" that did the job. Though I had to copy one folder at a time.